# MongoDB - JOINs between a time range

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query

I want to combine data on a time interval. Now I see the next vaviant:

**insert data:**

```
use mydb

db.items.insert( { name : "fakename1", created_at : 100, updated_at: 110 } )
db.items.insert( { name : "fakename1", created_at : 120, updated_at: 130 } )
db.items.insert( { name : "fakename1", created_at : 130, updated_at: 140 } )

db.items.insert( { name : "fakename2", created_at : 101, updated_at: 103 } )
db.items.insert( { name : "fakename2", created_at : 102, updated_at: 105 } )
db.items.insert( { name : "fakename2", created_at : 122, updated_at: 126 } )
```

**My query:**

```
db.items.find(
  { $and: [ 
    { created_at: { $gte: 100 } },
    { updated_at: { $lte: 130 }},
    { name: { $eq : "fakename1" }} 
    ] 
  }
).map(function(myDoc) {   
    myDoc.includes_items = db.items.find(
    { $and: [ 
      { created_at: { $gte: myDoc.created_at } }, 
      { updated_at: { $lte: myDoc.updated_at } },
      { name: { $ne : "fakename1" }}  
      ] 
    }).toArray(); 
    return myDoc; 
  }
)
```

**In result:**

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ab2f2eafc914fa3475f42f"),
        "name" : "fakename1",
        "created_at" : 100,
        "updated_at" : 110,
        "includes_items" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58ab2f32afc914fa3475f432"),
                "name" : "fakename2",
                "created_at" : 101,
                "updated_at" : 103
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58ab2f32afc914fa3475f433"),
                "name" : "fakename2",
                "created_at" : 102,
                "updated_at" : 105
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("58ab2f2eafc914fa3475f430"),
        "name" : "fakename1",
        "created_at" : 120,
        "updated_at" : 130,
        "includes_items" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("58ab2f32afc914fa3475f434"),
                "name" : "fakename2",
                "created_at" : 122,
                "updated_at" : 126
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but call **myDoc.events** takes a long time. I want to replace it, use the function [$lookup (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), but I do not know how to do it. Maybe I should use [MapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/)?

Comment: that query says that for every single document in the first find, it's going to do another find looking for the same things.  so if there are 10 documents, it'll do 11 finds.  Terrible practice, but you could put a limit 1 on the first search and I think it would do what you wanted.

Comment: @dnlbmn I understand that this is a terrible practice, but I could not find any other way to do it, so I ask how this can be changed. Maybe I should use MapReduce?

Comment: Can you use the [edit] link to update your question by including some sample documents that we can use for testing and what your expected output is for that sample?

Comment: @chridam I changed question.

Comment: this is textbook case of trying to enforce structure on a NoSQL database.  Either push the order_item into an array within the order document rather than adding a new first class document, or use a SQL data store.  See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: @dnlbmn I can not update the data in each document, because I have 10 thousand different "name" and they can all be linked by time interval.